# super not in operator position?

Tags: scala

in Scala there is syntactic sugar by calling a method when the method call is in operator position. For example `(5).+(3)` can be written as `5 + 3`. The rule for this is `<object>.<method>(<parameter>)`. It this rule is true the dot and the parentheses can be left. But I found an exception of this rule: it is not able to write the super-keyword in operator position:

```
class X {
  def x(i: Int) = i * 2
}
class Y extends X {
  override def x(i: Int) = super.x(i + 1)
}
```

When I leave the dot behind the super I get a compiler error. Here, `super` is the object, `x` the method and `i + 1` the parameter therefore I don't understand why I get an error. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is because the `super` keyword must (but see the comment by huynhjl and details below) be followed with a `.` and then followed with a valid member identifier -- *it seems to be grammar production rule*.

Consider that `val expr = (super)` has no useful meaning and should always be invalid (in this regard it is quite different from `this` which is a valid expression by itself). Requiring the `super.member` form at the grammar level is <del>likely intentional, but it would require some digging.</del> intentional per the wording the specification (see the comment by huynhjl) and per the grammar "summary" rules.

```
class X {
  def x(): X = this
}
class Y extends X {
  // Still kaboom of course -- message is effectively the same
  // and indicates a grammar production has been violated.
  // Message: error: '.' expected but '}' found.
  override def x(): X = super
}
```

Happy coding.

---

Update (references):

From the [Scala Language Specification 2.8](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) discussing `super` in Section 6.5:

> > A reference `super.m` refers *statically* to a method or type `m` in the least proper
> >     supertype of the innermost template containing the reference. It evaluates to the
> >     member in the actual supertype of that template which is equal to `m` or which
> >     overrides `m`. The *statically* referenced member `m` must be a type or a method
> >     ...
> >     The super prefix may be followed by a trait qualifier `[T]`, as in `C.super[T].x`. This
> >     is called a *static* super reference. In this case, the reference is to the type or method of
> >     `x` in the parent trait of `C` whose simple name is `T`.

And from the Scala Syntax Summary (Chapter A):

```
stableId ::= id
           | Path ‘.’ id
           | [id ’.’] ‘super’ [ClassQualifier] ‘.’ id
```

Comment: Based on the wording of the spec, `super.m` or `super[T].m` are only used to refer to *methods* or *types* of the super type and parent traits.